# How to ensure successful authentication with scala reactivemongo play

Tags: mongodb, scala, authentication, reactivemongo

I am using reactivemongo to connect to MongoDB.

```
val connection: MongoConnection = driver.connection(hosts, options = conOpts, authentications = List(credentials))
val db = connection(database)
val collection = db(collection)
val resultData = collection.find(query, filter)
```

And the first time I try to query the database, I get a:

```
Error executing MongoDB Query reactivemongo.core.errors.DetailedDatabaseException: DatabaseException['not authorized for query on test.test' (code = 13)]
```

If I try again, the query usually succeeds.  I presume that this is because the authentication hasn't had time to successfully complete when the find method is called for the first time.

So I wonder if there is a way to check the status of the authentication in order to wait for its completion before querying the database?

Comment: First make sur your credentials and [authMode](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html) (SCRAM SHA1 required for fresh MongoDB 3.x) are ok. Then you can try the latest release 0.11.9 which provides `.database` resolution (with failover support instead of the existing `.db` function): `val db = connection.database(database)`; Take care, the result is `Future[DefaultDB]`.

Comment: Thanks.  Does 0.11.9 also work with Play 2.3? The reactivemongo website says: "The latest version of this plugin is for Play 2.4".  But later it adds: "The minimal Play version for 0.11.9 is 2.3.9", which seems to suggest that it is possible to have it working with 2.3.  However, when I try I get a: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.reactivemongo#play2-reactivemongo_2.11;0.11.9.play23: not found

Comment: No it doesn't (and probably won't)

Answer (score 0):

Reactivemongo > 0.11.x should support SHA1 authorization but is not the default, to enable it just add "?authMode=scram-sha1" at the end of your mongodb.uri

```
uri = "mongodb://userName:password@localhost/databaseName?authMode=scram-sha1"
```

- in order to proper set up users just follow official doc:
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/
- details about roles:
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/